# JSON fetching data using $http is not working in phonegap developer app

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cordova

I'm fetching some data from remote server using AngularJS $http. It's working in browser but not in phonegap developer app. But, ajax is working. What could be the problem!!

Here is the code I'm using.

```
$http({
    url: domain + "modulesinfo/list",
    method: "GET",
    //Added after some research // I'm testing on local server
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
.success(function(data){
    $scope.modules = data.response; 
    $scope.$apply();
})
.error(function(){
    navigator.notification.alert("You are damned", function(){

    }, "Not working", "OK");
});
```

I tried adding header after some research, But that didn't work.

Comment: It may be a [CORS restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Can you access a developper console on the device your are testing this ?

Comment: I'm able to log via adb logcat.

Comment: And I'm sure that Access-Control-Allow-Origin is already there in header of my PHP file I'm getting response from.

Comment: you should post your update as an answer to your question, and accept your own answer; otherwise, your question will continue to appear in the "unanswered" category

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/54885/088218e45b6ba9f6fe147d721ba42c9d
Yeah I know that. But, I hope this explains something. :P

Comment: yes, your post is useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http.jsonp(domain + "modulesinfo/list?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.modules = data.response;
})
.error(function(){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This solved my problem. Hope it help others.
Adding the callback=JSON_CALLBACK with the url is working in my case.

Comment: So your endpoint was a jsonp resource instead of a rest endpoint? That would have been useful information to provide in the question.